# Fixing the Quote Character

Tags: support, encoding

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418233/setting-viewstateuserkey-gives-me-a-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error) has left and right quote marks in the title rather than the regular ASCII quotes.  In the Question List view, the quotes don't display correctly.  The left quote looks like an E with a hachek (upside down ^) and the right quote doesn't display at all.

I figured the user was using an odd encoding so went to "fix" to use standard quotes.  In the edit view, I saw the rounded quotes properly.  After changing to straight ASCII quotes, they still appeared rounded in the list view.

I'm using Google Chrome.

Is this a feature of SO that the quotes are rounded?  Am I doing something wrong while editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a feature of SO that the quotes are rounded?

Yes.

And FWIW, they look fine in the Questions list to me...

Needed: screenshot of problem, description of platform, exact browser version.

Comment: OK this is really strange.  I had a reboot courtesy of my kids pressing the reset button, and now the display looks fine to me as well.  Maybe a bug in Chrome that the reboot fixed.