# Is there a way to ensure typographer's quotes in SE posts?

Tags: support, markdown, quotation-marks

None of [my posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11714/37) have ["typographer's" quotes](http://www.typographyforlawyers.com/?page_id=1322) in them, yet I [read that they are the standard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21603/164163) for SE, and have had them corrected often by other contributors.

I assume my browser (Safari) is doing something (or failing to do something) by default that produces this behavior.

Are there settings in SE (or perhaps in Safari), or keyboard shortcuts I can use to ensure that I get typographer's quotes in my posts?

Comment: Please don't. They look ugly.

Comment: Your reading of that answer might not be entirely accurate. All it's saying is that in (and only in) question titles, the system automatically converts normal quotation marks to “ and ” where appropriate.

Comment: And considering most of the quotes on SO are probably code, automagically replacing them (if not done very smartly) would make most of the code samples unusable.

Comment: @meagar: Yes, I should specify: the expectation probably varies from site to site (judging by the differing zeal with which my typewriter quotes get corrected). I expect coding sites aren't as comfortable with them; but certainly for TeX-LaTeX and Mathematica they should be the norm.

Comment: If you want this specifically on [mathematica.se], you should ask it on [meta.mathematica.se]

Comment: @cHao: Yes, certainly the replacement only makes sense in text.

Comment: @yoda: No. This is about any text anywhere. Part of the answer might be that some sites discourage it. But I see the corrections happening on posts I make on many sites.

Comment: Looks like double quotes get the smart quote treatment in titles automatically. They probably don't in body text because a) that's a lot trickier to not mess up (code, block quotes, what if one is missing) and b) they look horrible in many fonts at low point size (like body text on SE)

Comment: @BenBrocka: That's what I'd expected too (the former, if perhaps not the latter) but it's [not happening for me](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11714/37).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes it is, that's just a funny font in which the typographer's quotes look like typewriter quotes.  The raw title as displayed (note asymmetric quotes): `How do I get rid of a “jump” in my plot?`

Comment: @blahdiblah: Wow, you're right. That's a terrible font!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites automatically convert quotes in titles to typographer's quotes, but the change is not always obvious because of font choice.

In your case, on Mathematica.SE, the quotes are typographer's: `“jump”`

But look a lot like typewriter quotes:

[image: Quotes]

True typewriter quotes must be straight up and down so as to be interchangeable. While often curved, they might also only angle differently as in the font used in Mathematica.SE titles.

If you want to be completely sure that your quotes are correct, you can always type them directly instead of relying on conversion. The standard keyboard shortcut on OS X (which I surmise you're using as you mention Safari) is <kbd>option</kbd>+(<kbd>shift</kbd>)+<kbd>[</kbd> for smart opening (closing) quotes.

Now you're free to make titles with “subtly incorrect quotes.“